# maven test automation in vsts is executing my test cases twice

Tags: azure-devops, testng

Whenever I try to run my Automated test cases in vsts, all test cases are executing twice irrespective of pass/fail results. Can anyone please advice how to execute test cases just once.

its a selenium maven project with java and testng framework.

Comment: could you explain in detail, on how you are executing the automated test cases?

Comment: I am executing in two ways, one by triggering once a commit is pushed to vsts, second by manually clicking on Queue. in both ways my test are running twice

Comment: Can you share the settings for the task in VSTS and the detailed build logs?

Comment: @Eddie: In my Maven Project, under "Code Coverage Tool" I selected JaCoCo and when I set it back to None. My tests are running only once as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under "Code Coverage Tool" select None.[image]